# string permutation in java

Tags: java, recursion

//Not getting the correct output.I don't understand what's wrong with my code.

```java
class Solution {

  public List<String> find_permutation(String S) {
    // Code here
    List<String> ans = new ArrayList<>();
    int l = 0, r = S.length() - 1;
    permute(S, l, r, ans);

    return ans;

  }

  public static void permute(String S, int l, int r, List<String> ans) {
    if (l == r) {
      ans.add(S);
      return;
    }

    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
      swap(S, l, i);
      permute(S, l + 1, r, ans);
      swap(S, l, i);
    }
  }

  public static String swap(String S, int i, int j) {
    char c[] = S.toCharArray();
    char temp = c[i];
    c[i] = c[j];
    c[j] = temp;

    return String.valueOf(c);
  }

}
```

// output

```
ABC
```

Your Output:
ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC

Expected Output:
ABC ACB BAC BCA CAB CBA

Output Difference
ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC ABC

Comment: You're not assigning the result of your `swap()` operations to anything.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this method with something like this to get **[ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CBA, CAB]**

```
public static void permute(String S,int l,int r,List<String> ans){
        if(l==r){
            ans.add(S);
            return ;
        }
        
        for(int i=l;i<=r;i++){
            S =swap(S,l,i);
            permute(S,l+1,r,ans);
            S = swap(S,l,i);
            }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from OP's code?